# making a UIView and UICollectionView scroll together

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a UIView, below it a UICollectionview. Both are sitting on top of a master UIScrollview. I considered using viewForSupplementaryKind (UIcollectionview delegate method). Doesnt work in my case.

So I basically want the UIView and UICollectionview to scroll together as One whole scrollview.. Right now what happens is, when I scroll, the master UiScrollview needs to stop scrolling for the UICollectionView to take precedence and scroll.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe a picture of what you have going on. Its kinda hard to picture for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `UIView` and `UICollectionView` to move together, you should probably make the `UIView` the first item or the header of the first section in your `UICollectionView`.  This will be much easier than nesting together in a `UIScrollView`.

However, if you must nest them in a `UIScrollView` for some reason, you can implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method to detect scrolling in the `UICollectionView` and adjust the `contentOffset` property of the higher up `UIScrollView`.  This technique is covered in the WWDC 2013 session called "Exploring Scroll Views in iOS 7" (session 217), but should work just fine in iOS 6.  You can find the video [here](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) (developer login required).

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite easy: just add your UIView as a subview to your UICollectionView. You then don't need the UIScrollView.

```
[collectionView addSubview:someView];
```